# Asignación errónea en una matriz tridimensional en Java

Tags: java, matrices, matriz

Mi intención es imprimir las tres dimensiones de una matriz asignando almohadillas a cada uno de sus valores pero, no se imprime correctamente. He revisado varias veces mi código y pasando el debug mode parece que falla en los bucles de asignación de valor a las posiciones de la matriz, pero no encuentro el error.
Os agradecería la ayuda enormemente. Mi código es el siguiente:

```
public static char[][][] rellenaArray3D(int[][] matriz) {
        //inicializo primera dimensión
        
        char[][][] ret = new char[matriz.length][][];  //compruebo y asigna bien

        for (int i = 0; i < matriz.length; i++) {
            ret[i] = new char[matriz[i].length][]; //compruebo y asigna bien
            for (int j = 0; j < matriz[i].length; j++) {//inicializo la segunda
                        ret[i][j]=new char[matriz[i][j]];  //compruebo con el debug y asigna bien el length a esta dimensión.
                    
               //para rellenar la estructura con el char. 
            }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < ret.length; i++) { //i:length nº dimensiones              
            for (int j = 0; j < ret[i].length; j++) {       //j: filas y k:columnas
                for (int k = 0; k < ret[i][j].length; k++) {
                    ret[i][j][k] = '#';
                }
            }
        }
        return ret;

    }

    public static String imprimeMatriz3D(char[][][] matriz) {
        String ret = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < matriz.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < matriz[i].length; j++) {
                for (int k = 0; k < matriz[i][j].length; k++) {
                    ret += matriz[i][j][k];
                }
            }
            ret += "\n";
        }
        return ret;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

¿Cual es el aspecto visual que estas buscando?
He estado realizando algunas pruebas

```
 int [][] matriz = {{2,2,2},{2,2,2},{2,2,2}};
System.out.println(Principal.imprimeMatriz3D(Principal.rellenaArray3D(matriz)));
```

Y me da como resultado esto:

```
    ######
    ######
    ######
```

Comment: ¡Bienvenido a [es.so]! Cuando tengas suficiente [reputación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges) podrás comentar en la pregunta para pedir al OP que provea más detalles acerca de su problema. Además, necesitas explicar brevemente qué hace tu código: lee [answer].

Comment: Tendría que imprimir las tres dimensiones en dibujo. El primero es como una L, el segundo una E y el tercero otra. He conseguido hacerlo de una forma pero desglosando mucho la matriz y, me preguntaba si el código de arriba sería viable. Por tener otra forma de hacerlo.